# FreeRADIUS accept any password for one user only

Tags: radius, freeradius, freeradius2

I need to configure one user on FreeRADIUS to authenticate and generate an access-accept regardless of the password submitted by the user. I can see how to do this for all users, but how can I do this for a single user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still having this problem, you could try something like:

```
authorize {

   ...

    if (User-Name == "bob") {
        update control {
            Auth-Type := Accept
        }
    } else {
        # process other users using
        # eap or whatever
    }
    
    ...

}
```

in your virtual authorisation server definition. Obviously `bob` would be changed to whatever your special username is. You'd have to fit this into whatever other normal auth process you use.